# Why does GNU 'bc' have such a long copyright string?

Tags: bc, gpl

When you run 'bc' on a GNU system, it prints out the following text:

```
~$ bc
bc 1.07.1
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006, 2008, 2012-2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
```

In contrast to several other GNU utilities:

```
~$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and

```
~$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.3
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

and

```
~$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.30
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Is there any reason why bc lists out all of the copyright dates in such a way instead of just using "Copyright 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc."?

Comment: Just `alias bc='bc -q'` and forget about it.

bc will only print that "welcome" when its output is a terminal.

Comment: Your question asks "why", but the only appropriate answer is "because bc's devs like it so". I don't see any value in second-guessing them.

Comment: bc's notice gives the years of the creations of the various portions of the program still in the current release. And see https://danashultz.com/2013/10/09/copyright-notice-with-multiple-years-legitimate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bc` follows [the recommended GNU practices for copyright notices](https://www.gnu.org/prep/maintain/html_node/Copyright-Notices.html), which involves listing every single publication year, although the copyright notice here lists more years than saw `bc` releases (even including `dc` releases).

The other tools only list the year of last publication, using [gnulib’s `version_etc` function](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/version-etc.c) which only prints the year as last updated in gnulib.

See also [Copyright notice must be regularly updated while the project is active?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4282/118)